# Passenger + Apache + Rails - serve static assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

How do I have rails serve `/assets/stylesheets` and `/assets/javascripts`? I don't particularly care that rails serves the files, and I'm not sure why they're not found when I deploy to staging.

Comment: You need to precompile the assests first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### case 1: If the assets are not inside your app

The problem is you might be using stylesheets that are not inside your app.

In that case you need to tell passenger where to look for those files..So you need to first create a symlink like this:

`ln -s <path-to-your-hosted-assets>/assets assets`

usually you can check these symlinks here `/local/docroot` and do `ll` to see all the existing symlinks.

### case 2: If the assets are inside your app

Do precompile the assets and see if you can see the assets.

Hope it helps!

Comment: For me it was case 2. If you deploy via heroku, it runs `bundle rake assets:precompile` for you. If you don't use heroku, you need to manage this yourself.